# Azure Function Version Affecting GET Request

Tags: azure, azure-functions

When I try to set Azure Functions to stable versions 1.0.14 or 1.0.13 locally & in the Portal - I tend to receive a 500 error when trying to GET an endpoint. Through some debugging, I managed to correct this by changing the version to beta. No errors.

Has anyone else seen this issue? Is there any way around this without actually having to recreate the function using the desired version?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very useful information, thank you Jerry! I managed to solve my issue by recreating the Azure function without using .NET Standard. Azure lets you know that changing certain settings may lead to the function not working properly. After recreating with the proper runtime set in both portal and project, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

You probably mistake [Azuer Function SDK version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.net.sdk.functions/) for [Azure Function Runtime version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version).

> try to set Azure Functions to stable versions 1.0.14 or 1.0.13 locally & in the Portal

`1.0.14 or 1.0.13` you mentioned is SDK version(latest is `1.0.19` right now), which is used to build our function project. Of course we can't set SDK version on portal as build is done before we publish pre-compiled code to Azure. If we develop in browser, the build process and SDK version(the latest) is under the control of Azure.

> I managed to correct this by changing the version to beta. No errors.

You may have created a v2 function locally, hence function depends on beta runtime. And you specify a wrong version of 1.x like 1.0.14, so 1.0.11959 is used. We can see 500 error is caused by mismatched runtime and you have corrected it. If you have planned to work with v2 function(.net standard), nothing malfunctions so far.

And some more info about function runtime version.

### Function Runtime version

There are two major versions: 1.x for .Net Framework and 2.x for .Net Standard.

**Syntax**

1. Major version :`~1` for 1.x , `~2` for 2.x. With this format, function app on Azure is automatically updated to new minor versions of the runtime when they become available.
2. Minor version 1.x:`1.0.11959`; 2.x: `2.0.11961-alpha`, `2.0.12050-alpha`. (All versions available right now). Function app on Azure is kept on that version until we explicitly change it.

**Where to find**

1. Runtime version in Function app settings.
2. `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` in Application settings.

**Configuration**

Two scenarios we need to change runtime.

1. Major version change. ~1 to ~2 or reverse.

   We may see prompt below if there are functions in the app.

   > Major version upgrades can introduce breaking changes to languages and bindings. When upgrading major versions of the runtime, consider creating a new function app and migrate your functions to this new app.

   - In an empty function app(delete existing functions or create new app), change runtime in Function app settings.
   - We can directly set `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` in Application settings if published project depends on another runtime.
2. Minor version pinned to avoid breaking changes(probably the last time to use as 2.x is planned to be GA by this fall).

   See [breaking changes](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/129) in `2.0.12050-alpha(beta)`, we can pin `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` to `2.0.11961-alpha` and follow steps to work with changes and move to beta.

   Find [more breaking changes](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/132) to fix if our 2.x function runtime is pinned to some older version, which have all been removed on Azure.

**Wrong version handler**

If we specify a wrong version of 1.x like 1.0.14, Azure will leverage latest minor version instead. It is same with 2.x.

**For local dev**

Commonly speaking, local dev doesn't need runtime configuration because we choose Cli first(using tools like npm or VS does in background), we are clear about the major version at least.

Some local places to find function runtime version.

1. VS, New Function project v1 or v2.
2. VS/VSCode c# function, in functionappname.csproj, see `<AzureFunctionsVersion>v2</AzureFunctionsVersion>`.
3. VSCode, functionapp/.vscode/setting.json, see `"azureFunctions.projectRuntime": "~2"`
4. Function core tools(Cli), run `func`, we may see `Function Runtime Version:2.0.12050.0`
5. Start a function app in VS/VSCode/Cli, besides 4, we can also see Cli output `Starting Host (HostId=xx, InstanceId=xx, Version=2.0.12050.0, ..)`